# Observable not having map function in Angular 2.0 final release

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and downloaded the latest Angular 2.0 final release and I cannot see intellisense after http.get("Url").

I only subscribe, lift and add methods and no map function

Observable not having map function

Note : imported all the rxjs/Rx and ALL relevant imports but I don't see the map function

Comment: Please add your what have you tryied to import and failed + add the code of your observable. Please try to import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `map` function is not added to the Observable, but to it's prototype.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; // (1)

console.log(Observable.map); // is always undefined
console.log(Observable.prototype.map); // is not undefined if line (1) is included
```

See also this [plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mb1nQzNlTOlwoOTYtMSX?p=preview) and play with the rxjs map operator import statement to see that the import works.